# If a joint cdf is increasing in each argument, then the pdf is strictly positive a.s.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^d \to [0,1]$ be an absolutely continuous joint cdf and let it be strictly increasing in each argument. Does it imply that its pdf $f$ is strictly positive a.s. (with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^d}$)? I would be very thankful for a reference to a book.

My idea was to show that $F$ being strictly increasing implies that $\int_A f d\lambda > 0$ for any $A = (a_1,b_1) \times \ldots \times (a_d, b_d)$, where $(a_i, b_i)$ are open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. This would in turn imply that $f > 0$. However, I didn't manage to show any of these implications.

Comment: No, in the one-dimensional case for example it implies only that $f \geq 0$. There can be points where $f=0$.

Comment: @Karl I meant strictly positive a.s. I corrected the formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. We construct a counterexample in the plane. To make computations easy, we restrict ourselves to the unit square $U=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, but you will see that the idea extends to the entire plane easily. Define the set $N=[1/3,2/3]\times[1/3,2/3]$.

Consider the probability density function
$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0&(x,y)\not\in U,\\
0&(x,y)\in N,\\
9/8&(x,y)\in U \setminus N.
\end{cases}$

The associated marginal distribution functions are strictly increasing for arguments inside the unit interval. The idea easily extends to the whole space. For example, take a standard normally distributed vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, set its density to zero for arguments in the unit ball and renormalize to get a density function again.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I guess one needs continuity of $f$ to obtain that it is strictly positive...

Comment: Glad I could help. By the way, continuity of $f$ is not relevant. You can also let $f$ go down from $U$ to the null set $N$ in a continuous way. The problem is that the marginal distributions do not "feel" the sets where $f$ is null because they integrate it out.